# Organize search controller results in sections inside UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Table view with a Search bar (search display controller) I need to organize the results in sections ... At start there are 1 section and with the search result they can have 1 or 2 or 3 section...Do you have a good way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help someone http://stackoverflow.com/a/39388169/2033377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends how you are capturing your search results.

Typically you would want to have an NSMutableArray of NSArrays. That way your main array.count becomes your section count and row count becomes the count of the nested array at that indexpath.row
An array of NSDictionaries is also typical.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [mainArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[mainArray objectAtIndex:section] count];

}
```