# Implement Search bar and search display for the table view with sections

Tags: uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, xcode6.3

I am trying to implement search bar with search display feature in swift for the table view given below.

Screenshot of the table view

[image]

I am getting issue because my string array is in the following format.

```
["section name1" : ["list1", "list2"] ,"section name2" : ["list3", "list4"]]
```

I have added my code below for the table view.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dishtable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var namlbl: UILabel!
var Dishes = ["POPULAR Dishes": ["Biryani", "Tandori Chicken","Butter Chicken", "Vada Pav"],"A": ["Aloo baingan", "Aloo ki Tikki", "Amritsari fish"], "B": ["Baigan bharta", "Biryani"]];

var Filterval = ["POPULAR Dishes": ["Biryani", "Tandori Chicken","Butter Chicken", "Vada Pav"],"A": ["Aloo baingan", "Aloo ki Tikki", "Amritsari fish"], "B": ["Baigan bharta", "Biryani"]];

struct dish {
    let Dish : [String]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dishtable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    dishtable.dataSource = self
    dishtable.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    self.Filterval = self.Dishes.filter({( d: dish) -> Bool in
        let DishMatch = (d.Dish == scope)
        let stringMatch = d.Dish.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return DishMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text!)
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

let sections:Array<AnyObject> = ["POPULAR Dishes","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
var usernames = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cellID = "cell"

    let cell: UITableViewCell =  self.dishtable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as! UITableViewCell
    println("value : \(indexPath.section)")
    println("value 1: \(indexPath.row)")
     var d : dish
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {

        cell.textLabel!.text = Filterval[sections[indexPath.section] as! String]![indexPath.row]

    } else {

        cell.textLabel!.text = Dishes[sections[indexPath.section] as! String]![indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    println("Dishes section count : \(section)")
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        if section == 0 {
            return Filterval["POPULAR Dishes"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 1 {
            return Filterval["A"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 2 {
            return Filterval["B"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 3 {
            return Filterval["C"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 4 {
            return Filterval["D"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 5 {
            return Filterval["E"]!.count
        }
        else if section == 6 {
            return Filterval["F"]!.count
        }
        return 0
    } else {
    if section == 0 {
        return Dishes["POPULAR Dishes"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return Dishes["A"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 2 {
        return Dishes["B"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 3 {
        return Dishes["C"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 4 {
        return Dishes["D"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 5 {
        return Dishes["E"]!.count
    }
    else if section == 6 {
        return Dishes["F"]!.count
    }
    return 0

    }
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{

    return 27
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
    atIndex index: Int) -> Int{

        return index
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

        return self.sections[section] as? String
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var ban = ""

    ban = Dishes[sections[indexPath.section] as! String]![indexPath.row]

    println(ban)


}
```

I have tried the following links online, but unable to implement the search feature.

1. http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift
2. http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/13/search-display-controller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial
3. http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift

Can someone help me with search bar?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what the exact issue is? Are the search results not what you expect, does it crash etc?

Comment: Actually in search result is not working at all. I am getting the whole list as it is.

Comment: I don't see any code referencing the search view. Have you implemented anything to do with it yet?

Comment: I have removed it, I will add it and post the code again.

Comment: I have updated the code, I am getting error at "self.Filterval = self.Dishes.filter({( d: dish) -> Bool in" line. I tried searching solution online for this, but unable get anything.

Comment: This is in objective c, but with different logic. You can search this way also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39388169/2033377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the following changes and got the desired output.

I am storing my string array in the Core Data with a flag for POPUlAR FOOD in the Core Data and fetching these details and storing in different arrays according to alphabets.

Created a switch case to show the sections in the table view.

```
var distinctstring = [String]()
var arr = [String]()
var arrA = [String]()
var arrB = [String]()
var arrC = [String]()
var arrD = [String]()
var arrE = [String]()
var arrF = [String]()
var arrG = [String]()
var arrH = [String]()
var arrI = [String]()
var arrJ = [String]()
var arrK = [String]()
var arrL = [String]()
var arrM = [String]()
var arrN = [String]()
var arrV = [String]()
var arrX = [String]()
var arrZ = [String]()
var arrP = [String]()
var arrO = [String]()
var arrY = [String]()
var arrU = [String]()
var arrT = [String]()
var arrR = [String]()
var arrW = [String]()
var arrQ = [String]()
var arrS = [String]()


var poparr = [String]()
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
    as! UILocalizedIndexedCollation


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    distinctstring.append("POPULAR FoodS")
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Food")
    var request1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Food")
    if var resultsFood = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [Food]
    {
        //println("\n Food Results in Table view : \(resultsFood)")
        for resultsb in resultsFood
        {

            if (resultsFood.count > 0)
            {
                println("\(resultsb.Food_name) : \(resultsb.popularity) ")

                if (resultsFood.count > 0)
                {
                    var firstchar = resultsb.Food_name.substringToIndex(resultsb.Food_name.startIndex.successor())
                    distinctstring.append(firstchar)
                    println("firstchar : \(firstchar)")
                    switch firstchar {

                        case "A" :

                            arrA.append(resultsb.Food_name)


                        case "B" :

                            arrB.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "C" :

                            arrC.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "D" :

                            arrD.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "E" :

                            arrE.append(resultsb.Food_name)


                        case "F" :

                            arrF.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "G" :


                            arrG.append(resultsb.Food_name)


                        case "H" :

                            arrH.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "I" :

                            arrI.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "J" :

                            arrJ.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "K" :

                            arrK.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "L" :

                            arrL.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "M" :

                            arrM.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "N" :

                            arrN.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "O" :

                            arrO.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "P" :

                            arrP.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "Q" :

                            arrQ.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "R" :

                            arrR.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "S" :

                            arrS.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "T" :

                            arrT.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "U" :

                            arrU.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "V" :

                            arrV.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "W" :

                            arrW.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "X" :

                            arrX.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "Y" :

                            arrY.append(resultsb.Food_name)

                        case "Z" :

                            arrZ.append(resultsb.Food_name)



                        default:
                            println("No present")
                    }
                    arr.append(resultsb.Food_name)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println("No rows found")

            }

        }
        println("array A = \(arrA)")
        println("array B = \(arrB)")
        println("array C = \(arrC)")
        println("array D = \(arrD)")
        println("array E = \(arrE)")
        println("array F = \(arrF)")
        println("array G = \(arrG)")
        println("array H = \(arrH)")
        println("array I = \(arrI)")
        println("array J = \(arrJ)")
        println("array K = \(arrK)")
        println("array L = \(arrL)")
        println("array M = \(arrM)")
        println("array N = \(arrN)")
        println("array O = \(arrO)")
        println("array P = \(arrP)")
        println("array Q = \(arrQ)")
        println("array R = \(arrR)")
        println("array S = \(arrS)")
        println("array T = \(arrT)")
        println("array U = \(arrU)")
        println("array V = \(arrV)")
        println("array W = \(arrW)")
        println("array X = \(arrX)")
        println("array Y = \(arrY)")
        println("array Z = \(arrZ)")


       distinctstring = uniq(distinctstring)

    }

    if var resultsFood1 = context.executeFetchRequest(request1, error: nil) as? [Food]
    {
        //println("\n Food Results in Table view : \(resultsFood)")
        for resultsb in resultsFood1
        {

            if (resultsFood1.count > 0)
            {

                //println("\n Table view Results ")
                //println("Value of Foodname Array : \(resultsb)")
                if (resultsFood1.count > 0)
                {
                    if (resultsb.popularity == 1)
                    {    println("Value of pop Foodname Array \(resultsb.Food_name) : \(resultsb.popularity) ")
                        poparr.append(resultsb.Food_name)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println("No rows found")

            }

        }
        println("poparr = \(poparr)")

    }


    self.Foodtable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    Foodtable.dataSource = self
    Foodtable.delegate = self
    //searchBar.delegate = self

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by Food name"
        self.Foodtable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.Foodtable.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // 2
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {



        switch distinctstring[section]
        {

        case "POPULAR FOOD" :

            return self.poparr.count

        case "A" :

            return self.arrA.count


        case "B" :

            return self.arrB.count

        case "C" :

            return self.arrC.count

        case "D" :

            return self.arrD.count

        case "E" :

            return self.arrE.count


        case "F" :

            return self.arrF.count

        case "G" :


            return self.arrG.count


        case "H" :

            return self.arrH.count

        case "I" :

            return self.arrI.count

        case "J" :

            return self.arrJ.count

        case "K" :

            return self.arrK.count

        case "L" :

            return self.arrL.count

        case "M" :

            return self.arrM.count

        case "N" :
            return self.arrN.count
        case "O" :
            return self.arrO.count
        case "P" :
            return self.arrP.count
        case "Q" :
            return self.arrQ.count
        case "R" :
            return self.arrR.count
        case "S" :
            return self.arrS.count
        case "T" :
            return self.arrT.count
        case "U" :
            return self.arrU.count
        case "V" :
            return self.arrV.count
        case "W" :
            return self.arrW.count
        case "X" :
            return self.arrX.count
        case "Y" :
            return self.arrY.count
        case "Z" :
            return self.arrZ.count


        default:

            return self.arr.count

        }

    }
}

func uniq<S: SequenceType, E: Hashable where E==S.Generator.Element>(source: S) -> [E] {
    var seen: [E:Bool] = [:]
    return filter(source) { seen.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil }
}

///////////////////////////////////////Section

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

           return (distinctstring.count)

}


   ///////////////////////////////////////Section

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var dishes = ""
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

        dishes = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]


    }
    else {
    println("distinctLetters : \(distinctstring[indexPath.section])")
        switch (distinctstring[indexPath.section]) {


        case "POPULAR FOOD" :

            dishes = poparr[indexPath.row]

        case "A" :

            dishes = arrA[indexPath.row]

        case "B":

            dishes = arrB[indexPath.row]

        case "C":

            dishes = arrC[indexPath.row]

        case "D" :

            dishes = arrD[indexPath.row]

        case "E":

            dishes = arrE[indexPath.row]

        case "F":

            dishes = arrF[indexPath.row]

        case "G" :

            dishes = arrG[indexPath.row]

        case "H":

            dishes = arrH[indexPath.row]

        case "I":

            dishes = arrI[indexPath.row]

        case "J" :

            dishes = arrJ[indexPath.row]

        case "K":

            dishes = arrK[indexPath.row]

        case "L":

            dishes = arrL[indexPath.row]

        case "M" :

            dishes = arrM[indexPath.row]

        case "N":

            dishes = arrN[indexPath.row]

        case "O":

            dishes = arrO[indexPath.row]

        case "P" :

            dishes = arrP[indexPath.row]

        case "Q":

            dishes = arrQ[indexPath.row]

        case "R":

            dishes = arrR[indexPath.row]

        case "S" :

            dishes = arrS[indexPath.row]

        case "T":

            dishes = arrT[indexPath.row]

        case "U":

            dishes = arrU[indexPath.row]

        case "V" :

            dishes = arrV[indexPath.row]

        case "W":

            dishes = arrW[indexPath.row]

        case "X":

            dishes = arrX[indexPath.row]

        case "Y" :

            dishes = arrY[indexPath.row]

        case "Z":

            dishes = arrZ[indexPath.row]
            //return sectionHeaderView
        default:

            dishes = arr[indexPath.row]
        }



    }
    println("row selected : \(dishes)")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {


        return ""
    }
    else {
             return "\(distinctstring[section])"
    }

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell;
    cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)

    //println("distinctLetters in cell : \(distinctLetters[indexPath.section]) ")
    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 2;
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {


        switch (distinctstring[indexPath.section]) {

        case "POPULAR FOOD" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = poparr[indexPath.row]
        case "A" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrA[indexPath.row]

        case "B":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrB[indexPath.row]

        case "C":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrC[indexPath.row]

        case "D" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrD[indexPath.row]

        case "E":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrE[indexPath.row]

        case "F":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrF[indexPath.row]

        case "G" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrG[indexPath.row]

        case "H":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrH[indexPath.row]

        case "I":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrI[indexPath.row]

        case "J" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrJ[indexPath.row]

        case "K":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrK[indexPath.row]

        case "L":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrL[indexPath.row]

        case "M" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrM[indexPath.row]

        case "N":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrN[indexPath.row]

        case "O":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrO[indexPath.row]

        case "P" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrP[indexPath.row]

        case "Q":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrQ[indexPath.row]

        case "R":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrR[indexPath.row]

        case "S" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrS[indexPath.row]

        case "T":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrT[indexPath.row]

        case "U":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrU[indexPath.row]

        case "V" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrV[indexPath.row]

        case "W":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrW[indexPath.row]

        case "X":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrX[indexPath.row]

        case "Y" :

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrY[indexPath.row]

        case "Z":

            cell.textLabel?.text = arrZ[indexPath.row]
            //return sectionHeaderView
        default:

            cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }Food
    //return cell;
}


   func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (arr as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.Foodtable.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend restructuring your `Dishes` array like so:

```
var Dishes = [["title":"POPULAR Dishes", "data":["Biryani", "Tandori Chicken","Butter Chicken", "Vada Pav"]], ["title":"A", "data":["Aloo baingan", "Aloo ki Tikki", "Amritsari fish"]], ["title":"B", "data":["Baigan bharta", "Biryani"]]]
```

And changing this like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  println("Dishes section count : \(section)")
  if let sectionData = Dishes[section] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let dataArray = sectionData["data"] as? [String] {
      return dataArray.count
    }
  }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: I have done the changes and I am getting "Count not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments" in the tableView fund for "cellForRowAtIndexPath".