# How to make different search field for every sections in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

Suppose I want to implement UITableview with search field for each section. If I search in first sections resulted rows should be updated in first sections only. Same way if i search in second section, Second section resulted rows should be update and so on for rest of the sections.

I had implement with each section search field but it reloads section when i am reloading section or reload rows for section.

Comment: Please post some code, so we can see what exactly is the problem. Maybe how you reload the section when a search is executed.

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same scenario. I also want to use section-wise search. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/39388169/2033377

Comment: @DeepakThakur I am looking for different searchbars for 2 sections. Thanks for your comment but it won't help me. Also I have already found solution for it. you can find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, please find below code for it. As i am using AutoLayout & Storyboard for my view controller I took IBOutlets and as of now I have only 2 sections so I declared as static, but you can make this dynamic by creating views if you have more sections.

```
// define in your .h file and take layout for the views and make it saperate from your main view container (outside of main view controller).
 
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextField * txtSearchSection1;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextField * txtSearchSection2;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewSection1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewSection2;


// Implement in your .m file 
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40.0f;
}
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==1) {
        return _viewSection1;
    }else{
        return _viewSection2;
    }
}
```