# UITableView, Search Bar and section index

Tags: ios, uitableview, searchbar

Hello I was trying to use UITableView, and i added a SearchBar in viewDidLoad method as follows:
[image]

and a section index bar with the following method:
[image]

my question is :

1- is possible to push down the index bar so that it does not cover the SearchBar

2- is possible to scroll up the entire tableView in viewDidLoad method to hidden SearchBar at that the startup of the application

[image]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/39388169/2033377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the easiest way to achieve this, but it works.

The first thing would be to not add the search bar as a header view, but rather to have it and a table view added to a separate scroll view. Something like this (margins for ilustratory purposes only) : light blue is the underlying scroll view
[image: nested views]

This, automatically fixes issue #1 - the index bar is now under the search bar.

Now, because of this nested scroll views (a table view is a subclass of scroll view) if we want to have a smooth scrolling experience, we need to subclass `UIScrollView` like that :

```
class InnerScrollView: UIScrollView {
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
    }
}
```

and use this class as our underlying scroll view - either in code, or by setting it in Interface Builder. This makes it so that, when the user scrolls, the search bar will appear/disappear first and then the table view content will scroll smoothly.

As to the initial offset, this will need to be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, as this is the first place where you can be sure that the scroll views have been setup.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let initalContentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:self.tableView.frame.origin.y)
    self.underlyingScrollView.contentOffset = initalContentOffset

}
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.